# Issue with useNavigate() Hook in Custom React-Admin Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-admin

I'm facing a challenging issue in my React-Admin application. When I try to use the `useNavigate()` hook within my custom login component (`MyLoginPage`), I'm getting the following error:

`[Route] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`

**Problematic Behavior:**
The error occurs exclusively within `MyLoginPage`, which is set as the loginPage prop in the `<Admin>` component of React-Admin, suggesting it should inherently have routing context.

**Setup:**

Shell Component: Acts as a wrapper around React-Admin's `<Admin>` for Firebase auth state handling.
`MyLoginPage` component: Custom login component using `useNavigate()` for post-login redirects.
Here's a snippet from `MyLoginPage` where `useNavigate()` is invoked:

MyLoginPage component

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
// ... other imports

const MyLoginPage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // this line triggers the error
  // ... rest of the component
};
```

And here's how `MyLoginPage` is used within the app structure:

App component

```
import { Admin } from "react-admin";
import MyLoginPage from "./MyLoginPage";
import { Shell } from "./Shell";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Shell>
      <Admin loginPage={MyLoginPage} /* ... other props ... */>
        {/* ... resources ... */}
      </Admin>
    </Shell>
  );
};
```

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- Ensured `MyLoginPage` is rendered as a child of `<Admin>`.
- Checked for additional `<Router>` instances that might conflict with React-Admin's router context.

I'm stumped as to why `useNavigate()` is losing context within `MyLoginPage`. Could this be an issue with the order in which components are mounted? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the error message not clear enough? The `useNavigate` hook can only be used within a routing context provided by a router component. Where are you rendering a router in relation to this `MyLoginPage` component? Can you [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] that includes the router and routes, and everything between through to the `MyLoginPage` component?

Comment: Appreciate the response. In react-admin, the <Admin> component provides a router context, so typically, there's no need to render a <Router>. The MyLoginPage is used within <Admin> which should pass down the routing context automatically, hence the confusion when useNavigate() doesn't work as expected.

// App component structure
<Shell>
  <Admin loginPage={MyLoginPage}>
    {/* resources */}
  </Admin>
</Shell>

I'm trying to figure out if there's a subtle issue with the context propagation in react-admin.

Comment: I see. Well my guess then is that the `MyLoginPage` needs to be rendered *under* this `Admin` component since it needs access to the routing context. Try rendering `MyLoginPage` on a `"/login"` `Route` manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I've managed to resolve the issue. It turns out I was missing the `react-admin-firebase` package in my dependencies, which is crucial for integrating Firebase authentication with React-Admin. After adding it to my project, the useNavigate() hook is now working correctly within my MyLoginPage component. Thank you to everyone for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Re, indeed my previous answer was not logical, but adding a dependency is probably not the solution.

Your problem is well described in the doc and the resolution is in npm (package.json).

[link to doc section troobleshooting](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Routing.html)

### Troubleshooting

When using custom routing configurations, you may encounter strange error messages like:

`useLocation()` may be used only in the context of a  component

or

`useNavigate()` may be used only in the context of a  component

or

`useRoutes()` may be used only in the context of a  component

or

`useHref()` may be used only in the context of a  component.

or

`<Route>` may be used only in the context of a `<Router>` component

These errors can happen if you added `react-router` and/or `react-router-dom` to your dependencies, and didn’t use the same version as react-admin. In that case, your application has two versions of react-router, and the calls you add can’t see the react-admin routing context.

You can use the `npm list react-router` and `npm list react-router-dom` commands to check which versions are installed.

If there are duplicates, you need to make sure to use only the same version as react-admin. You can deduplicate them using yarn’s resolutions or npm’s overrides.

// in packages.json

```json
{
    // ...
  "resolutions": {
    "react-router-dom": "6.7.0",
    "react-router": "6.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: React-admin wrap its component automaticaly with a react router, that"s why we can use useNavigate inside the login component there.

I've managed to resolve the issue. It turns out I was missing the react-admin-firebase package in my dependencies, which is crucial for integrating Firebase authentication with React-Admin. After adding it to my project, the useNavigate() hook is now working correctly within my MyLoginPage component. Thank you to everyone for your time and assistance!